# How to Show Image in django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I am newbie in django. I would like to make upload image and to show image from database, but I am not able to show image. I already asked this but the trouble is not solved.

**model.py**:

```
class Static(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description     = models.TextField()
    images1         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")
    images2         = models.ImageField(upload_to="slider")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**view.py**:

```
def home(request):
sliders     = Static.objects.all()
posts       = Product.objects.all().order_by("-created_date")
paginator   = Paginator(posts,6)
page        = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    posts = paginator.page(1)
except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
    posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'kerajinan/home.html', {
    'posts'         : posts,
    'sliders'       : sliders,
    'categories'    : Category.objects.all(),
})
```

**settings.py**:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
MEDIA_URL  = '/static/images/'
```

**urls.py**:

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^home/$', 'kerajinan.views.home', name='home'),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**home.html**

```
{% for i in sliders %}
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h2>{{i.title}}</h2>
                <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="{{ i.images1.url }}" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" />
                <img src="{{ i.images2.url }}" class="pricing" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I already checked in python manage.py shell and query data. The result is record data.
Can you help me to solve this trouble?

Comment: What is value of src property in generated html?Is it empty?

Comment: yes, it is empty. how?

Comment: `url(r'^home/$', 'kerajinan.views.home', name='home')`  
What's on your home method?  
Should it be `url(r'^home/$', 'kerajinan.views.slider', name='home')`

Comment: Ya @moonstruck that's right...! apsi Did you noticed ?

Comment: I already change view.py like above. but its not working. what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

> MEDIA_URL & STATIC_URL settings must have different values

so other than `static/images` give anything you like `other/images` or `life/images` etc... will work..

Why the so much confuses...

Actually recommended way to give media

`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

and in your urls remove the static serve and do ...

`) +static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

And one more thing change the `render_to_response` to `render`

Comment: i already change urls.py like above, but its not image cannot show. how?

Comment: This is correct answer and then document describes, too.

Comment: Thanks Tony. @apsi Did you tried everything what i told...?